# How to interlace links and text inside a p with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, dom

If I have HTML code like so

```
  <p>
   If you want to google something just go to <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
  </p>
```

I can generate this in jquery like so

```
 $('<p>').prop({
      innerHTML: 'If you want to google something just go to <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>'
  })
```

I mostly do this because I can move the `<a>` tag out to its own block and bind functions to the links like so

```
  $('<p>').prop({
      innerHTML: 'If you want to google something just go to '
  }).append(
    $('<a>').prop({
      innerHTML: 'www.google.com',
      href: '#'
    }).click(function (){
        alert ('Gotcha!');
    })
  )
```

But I can't wrap my head around how I would accomplish this if I have HTML like so

```
<p>
   If you want to google something just go to <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a> but for a wild time, go to <a href='www.urbandictionary.com'>Urban Dictionary</a>
<p>
```

How do I *put* text between the links? Is there a way to disable the newline? Should I dump everything into a div and not a p?

Minimmal Jsfiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/eofczuLn/

Comment: FYI, I use links to make complex API calls (eg. `/logout`, `/get_all_users`, etc.) so I bind functions to their `click` events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [insertAdjacentText()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenttext.asp)

```js
let link = $("#target a")[0];
link.insertAdjacentText("beforebegin","(before the link)");
link.insertAdjacentText("afterbegin","(inside before)")
link.insertAdjacentText("beforeend","(inside after)");
link.insertAdjacentText("afterend","(after the link)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="target">
  <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
  <a href='www.urbandictionary.com'>www.urbandictionary.com</a>
<p>
```

To access all contents, including text nodes in the paragraph you can run this in console:

```
$("#target").contents();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/m2hctL8b/16/

```
$(function() {
  var p1 = $("<p>").html('If you want to google something just go to <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>');
  $("a", p1).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Surprise!");
  });

  p1.appendTo("#example_1b_jquery");


  var p2 = $("<p>").html("If you want to google something just go to <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a> but for a wild time, go to <a href='www.urbandictionary.com'>Urban Dictionary</a>");

  $("a", p2).eq(0).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Got you again!");
  });

  $("a", p2).eq(1).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Wow! Again, surprise!");
  });

  p2.appendTo("#example_2_jquery");
});
```

You can use `.find()` or properly select HTML Elements from a HTML Srting as needed. If the selector may have more than 1 element, you can use `.eq()` or `:eq()` to help select the item by Index. So we can then assign two unique callbacks to each item.